# Javascript merge objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone suggest a better way of doing something like the following:

```
setData(start, end, country, person, type, data){
    this.cachedData[start] = this.cachedData[start] ? this.cachedData[start] : {};
    this.cachedData[start][end] = this.cachedData[start][end] ? this.cachedData[start][end] : {};
    this.cachedData[start][end][country] = this.cachedData[start][end][country] ? this.cachedData[start][end][country] : {};
    this.cachedData[start][end][country][person] = this.cachedData[start][end][country][person] ? this.cachedData[start][end][country][person] : {};
    this.cachedData[start][end][country][person][type] = data;
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately SO is not really for asking for suggestions on code that works. What you should do is try to come up with a better solution, probably using recursion. If it doesn't work, post what you tried; that's a better fit for this forum

Comment: Have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-merge for inspiration. I don't think it does exactly what you need, but it should give you a head start

Comment: Write a generic function for setting / getting (nested) properties on an object. Also note that this has nothing whatsoever to with JSON. JSON is a *textual* data representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it a bit more generic by allowing a variable number of arguments (ES6):

```js
class X {
    constructor() {
        this.cachedData = {};
    }
    setData(...args){
        var obj = this.cachedData;
        var [key, data] = args.splice(-2, 2);
        for (var prop of args) {
            obj = obj[prop] = obj[prop] || {};
        }
        obj[key] = data;
    }
}

x = new X();
x.setData('2016', '2017', 'Germany', 'Jack', 'green', 'light');
x.setData('2016', '2017', 'Germany', 'Helen', 'red', 'dark');
console.log(x.cachedData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
function setData (start, end, country, person, type, data){
    var data_path = [start, end, country, person];
    var person = data_path.reduce( function ( ref, prop ) { 
      return ref[prop] = ref[prop] || {};
    }, this.cachedData );
    person[ type ] = data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a loop and in case of undefined or null, you can replace {}. I dont see any other way.

Anybody have one?